# How to create the border shown in the picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How would I go about creating this type of border? [Large image](http://www.meetup.com/NightPhotography/photos/2225761/#37870211).

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 2):

That's someone using the Inner Glow layer effect.
Set the Technique to Precise rather than Softer, and a Size of 25-ish px. It will even give you that "corner line".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, double-click the background layer to make it a normal layer. Then apply a Bevel & Emboss layer style. I tried Inner Bevel and it looked about like the sample. You can play with the parameters -- size and soften. A lot of it depends on the size of your image. Hope this gets you started. You might also try Emboss or Pillow Emboss instead of Inner Bevel to see if you like those effects better.